# Add function call as parameter to onclick function onclick="foobar(cb_func)"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using onclick for an element, but need to pass a callback to it like this:

```
function cb_func() {
    alert("hello world!");
}

function foobar(i, cb) {
    do something

    if (cb != undefined)
        cb();
}

onclick="javascript:foobar(1, cb_func)"
```

foobar gets called, but my cb_func isn't - in fact when I step in to cb() usinf Firebug, it shows me the HTML for the entire page.

Any ideas how I might achieve this?

Comment: avoid using onclick attributes, try JQuery `$('.element').click(functionID);`

Comment: posted code is okay: http://jsfiddle.net/y1cjgo63/

Comment: Actually, the HTML is dynamically added to the DOM and I can't reliably tell WHEN it is added so that I can then add my jQuery('XXX').click handler, so I HAVE to use onclick...

Comment: @Sim `so I HAVE to use onclick` No, you don't! Use delegation to bind event, avoid using inline scripting

Comment: The code you've supplied should work fine as shown here: http://jsbin.com/weyicafuje/edit?html,js,output. Sounds like the issue lies elsewhere. What is the "do something" code?

Comment: @Sim jquery / javascript can be run at anytime, to bind a handler function to a click event just recall the js that adds the handler after the dynamic creation of the new elements

Answer (score 1):

Use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).on('click', '.dynamicGeneratedEl', function(event){

  // do something
  cb_func();

});
```

Where `.dynamicGeneratedEl` is a suitable selector for your case.

Answer (score 0):

> comment the line `// do something`

```
 function cb_func() {
            alert("hello world!");
        }

        function foobar(i, cb) {
            // do something

            if (cb != undefined)
                cb();
        }
```

Comment: That was just for illustration, that's NOT actually in the code

Comment: @Sim So can you provide jsFiddle replicating your issu because actually i don't see any

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

https://jsfiddle.net/h3ckcgvv/2/

```
var nextFunction = function() {
    // some more stuff happens 
}

var processClick = function() {
    // some stuff happens
    // condition
      nextFunction();
}

$('.js-click-me').click(processClick);
```

The condition could be anything, based on page inspection, javascript variable state, data attributes on the clicked HTML element etc. Much more stable and maintainable than `onclick` attributes and hardcoding the callback into every call where it's needed.